# How does SSMS show partial results of a large resultset whilst the query is still running, and can equivalent behaviour be achieved in .NET?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, ssms, resultset

In SQL Server Management Studio, when running a query that produces a very large resultset, it appears to sometimes display the results of the resultset as it's loading them, rather than them all appearing at once.

My normal assumption would be that it's simply it populating the grid(s) in SSMS with the results of the finished query, and that the SQL query itself is finished.

However, if I run the following query:

```
SELECT 1
SELECT * FROM EnormousTable
INSERT INTO SomeOtherTable([Column1]) SELECT 'Test3'
```

That last `INSERT` does not occur until after the results from the larger resultset have been fully returned.

I have two main questions:

**1. What is happening here?**  Is SSMS breaking down the query into separate batches even without `GO` statements?  Please note that I'm not a DBA, so if there's some fundamental reason for this behaviour that 'any DBA would know', there's a good chance I don't know it.

**2. Is there a way to attain similar functionality in .NET?**  What I mean by this is, when running a set of queries that will produce multiple resultsets, whether or not it's possible to have a `DataSet` get populated with the results of each successive query as it finishes (without waiting for all the queries to finish), without me having to manually break down the query (unless that's what SSMS is actually doing under the hood).